# Unexpected Manipulate behavior

Tags: manipulate, version-10, gui-construction

I get unexpected results when I run the following code (even before moving the sliders):

```
  InfPoint[ang_] := If[ang <= 1 , 5, 0];
  Manipulate[
    Print[0,    "\t", InfPoint[0]];
    Print[ang, "\t", InfPoint[ang]],
    {x, 0, 2},
    {ang, x, 2}
  ]
```

> ```
> 0 5
> 0   If[0<=1,5,0]
> ```

Notice that calling `InfPoint` with an argument fails to evaluate, even
though the argument seems to be passed correctly.  When I change the last "x" in the code to a "0", everything works as expected.

This code is modeled after this example found at tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality, which seems to work just fine:

```
Manipulate[
  Row[{
    "(",
    Column[{n,m},Center],
    ")=",
    Binomial[n,m]  
  }],
  {n,1,10,1},
  {m,1,n,1}
]
```

There's something going on here that I don't understand. Can anyone explain to me how I should think about these nested controls?

(I am running Mathematica 10.0.2.0.)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One difficulty in using `Manipulate` is that it rewrites your code for you in ways that are not clearly explained in the documentation.  The thinking is that this rewriting achieves the dynamic interactions described in the documentation without burdening the programmer with some of the tedious details involved.  For instance, expressions that contain `Manipulate` variables get wrapped in `Dynamic`, so that they will be updated when the variable changes.  This allows controls to interact with each other.  But exactly how and when code is rewritten is not clearly explained.

The documentation somewhat vaguely suggests that a variable/control declaration of the form

```
{var, a, b}
```

should be equivalent to

```
{{var, a}, a, b}
```

For instance, from [`tutorial/IntroductionToManipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToManipulate.html#498667553):

> It would be convenient to set their initial value to something other than the default left-most value. This is done by using a variable specification of the form `{{var, init}, min, max}`.

In the OP's case, the declaration

```
{ang, x, 2}
```

should be written

```
({ang, x}, Dynamic[x], 2}
```

and result in a control

```
Manipulator[Dynamic[ang], {Dynamic[x], 2}]
```

placed in the `Manipulate` output when shown in the Front End, with `ang` initialized to `x`.  This is what [m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg) and [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) were referring to in their answer and comment respectively.

In fact what seems to happen is that the rewrite results in

```
{ang, Dynamic[x], 2}
```

which is equivalent, by the default initialization rule, to

```
{{ang, Dynamic[x]}, Dynamic[x], 2}
```

which also explains what Kuba observed.

In my opinion, this behavior is avoidable and should be considered a bug.  However, WRI developers might disagree with me.

Note that we do not run into this problem with the example from the tutorial cited by the OP.  The declaration

```
{m, 1, n, 1}
```

is rewritten

```
{m, 1, Dynamic[n], 1}
```

-- is equivalent to

```
{{m, 1}, 1, Dynamic[n], 1}
```

-- and results in the control

```
Manipulator[Dynamic[m], {1, Dynamic[n], 1}]
```

in the output with `m` initialized to `1`.  Since it is not initialized to `Dynamic[n]`, we do not see the same problem as in the OP's code.

A workaround, as m_goldberg already pointed out, is to initialize `ang` explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do some initialization. `Manipulate` often behaves strangely when its controls are not initialized properly.

```
f[u_] := If[u <= 1, 5, 0];

Manipulate[
  Column[{
    Row[{"x: ", x, "    f[x]: ", f[x]}],
    Row[{"ang: ", ang, "  f[ang]: ", f[ang]}]}],
  {x, 0, 2},
  {{ang, x}, x, 2}]  (* initialization added to control *)
```

[image: demo]